# Convert SQL to JPA 2 Criteria queries

Tags: java, jpa, jpa-2.0

I've successfully created some JPA 2 criteria queries, but im now converting a query that is too complex for me to be able to convert it. Anyone up for a challenge? I will be eternally thankful for any response! :)

This is the query in plain SQL (mysql):

```
SELECT o.orderId, oi.insertDate 
FROM AIDA_ORDER o
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    (SELECT orderId, MIN(insertDate) AS insertDate FROM AIDA_ORDER_INSERT 
    WHERE insertDate > CURDATE() GROUP BY orderId) AS oi
ON oi.orderId = o.orderId
ORDER BY oi.insertDate, o.orderId;
```

The AIDA_ORDER table corresponds to a OrderBean, and AIDA_ORDER_INSERT to a OrderInsertBean.
A AIDA_ORDER can have multiple AIDA_ORDER_INSERTS.

Comment: `Anyone up for a challenge?`. I will do it at a fee, of course! :p

Comment: Why not use JPQL instead?

Comment: I dont want to use JPQL because it is a dynamicly built up query. This is just the one variant im struggeling with.

Comment: You can create dynamic JPQL. I still don't know why specifically Criteria Builder.

Comment: I know you can. But creating dynamic JPQL does not guarantee a valid query-string, where as Criteria's give you more safety.